# Why is seoi-nage a hand technique?

Tags: judo, technique

What makes `seoi-nage` a hand technique instead of a hip technique? Is there something fundamentally different about it that separates it from hip techniques like `o-goshi` and `koshi guruma`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After thinking about it, the answer might be really obvious. `Seoi-nage` can be translated as `shoulder throw` or `back carry`. Instead of loading uke on the hips, tori loads uke onto his back. Since the hip isn't used in this action, it is not a hip technique.